# How to automatic login after activating a user account

Tags: laravel

After the user registered my website, the system will send an activation link to the user's email provided with the email and token. If the email and token matched with the database, then it should have to update the status. The status is successfully updated. What I want now is to login automatically after clicking the link.

Below is the code to check if the request is valid and should login after matching.

`http://localhost:8000/verify?email=[email]&token=[token]`

Controller

```
/* GET Method
*/
public function verify(Request $request)
{
    if( $request->email && $request->token )
    {   
        $user = \DB::table('users')
                ->where('email', '=', $request->email)
                ->where('verified_token', '=' , $request->token); 

        //if $user found then automatic login
    }
}
```

Below is my User.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
  use Notifiable;
  //more codes below
}
```

By the way, I am using laravel 5.4

Answer (score 3):

You could manually authenticate the user using the [`login`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication#other-authentication-methods)/[`loginUsingId`](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Auth/Guard.html#method_loginUsingId) method

```
public function verify(Request $request)
{
    if( $request->email && $request->token )
    {   
        $user = App\User::where([
                    ['email', '=', $request->email],
                    ['verified_token', '=' , $request->token]
                ])->first();

        //if $user found then automatic login
        if (!empty($user)) {
            $user->update(['status' => 1]); // Change the status
            Auth::loginUsingId($user->id); //login the user using the user id
            redirect('/home'); // redirect the user
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried this but error occured `Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, instance of stdClass given, Illuminate/Auth/AuthManager.php on line 294`

Comment: `The given object must be an implementation of the  Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable contract. Of course, the App\User model included with Laravel already implements this interface` Make sure your User model implements the `Authenticatable` interface

Comment: yeah I have. added it on my question

Comment: Try with the [`loginUsingId`](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Auth/Guard.html#method_loginUsingId) method

Answer (score 1):

Two ways to login in Laravel Application

**1.just pass object of user**

```
 $user = App\User::where([
                ['email', '=', $request->email],
                ['verified_token', '=' , $request->token]
            ])->first();
    if (!empty($user)) {
        $user=$user->update(['status' => 1]); 
        auth()->login($user); 
   }
```

**2) pass user id in `loginUsingId` method like this**

```
if (!empty($user)) {
    $user->update(['status' => 1]); 
    auth()->loginUsingId($user); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are retrieving a user model you can simply use the login function:

```
Auth::login($user);

// Login and "remember" the given user...
Auth::login($user, true);
```

Taken directly from the docs here:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#other-authentication-methods

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `Auth::login($user)` in this part `//if $user found then automatic login`, you can [visit this link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#other-authentication-methods) , since you're using *laravel5.4*.